# Which of intervals of given function does have one real root?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

$f(x) = 3x^3 - 2x^2 +2x-8$

Which of intervals of given function does have only one real root?

a) $(-2,1)$ b) $(-1,0)$ c) $(3,4)$ d) $(1,2)$ e) $(2,3)$

On the condition that a function has only one real root, then the signs are different, right?

Regards!

Comment: The derivative is $6x^2-4x+2=2x^2+1+(2x-1)^2$, which is always positive. Therefore, that function is always increasing. This means that in order for it to have a root inside an interval it must take different signs at its end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the derivative, which is $f'(x)= 6x^2−4x+2=2x^2+1+(2x−1)^2$. Hence, the derivative is always positive and $f$ thus always increasing. Since it is always increasing, there is only one chance for it to cross the $x$-axis, i.e. have a root. Simply try out the intervals. We have $f(-2)=-44$ and $f(1)=-5$. Thus, there is no zero in the interval between -2 and 1 (if there were, one value of $f$ at the boundary would need to be positive). Thus, we are looking for an interval where $f$ takes a negative value at the left boundary and a positive value at the right boundary. The intermediate value theorem then guarantees us to find a zero in this interval. It is unique since the derivative is always positive. 
This is the case for (1,2) because $f(1)=-5$ and $f(2)=12$. Thus, d) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute $f(1)$ and $f(2)$